# Javascript webservice call run not existing code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

Today i'm trying to create some call to a webservice from javascript with asp.net and vb.net.

After a lot of trying i've done the job with this WebService code:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class WebService1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld(ToSomeone as String) As String
       Return "Hello World " + ToSomeone
    End Function

End Class
```

and this javascript call triggered from a button

```
function WebServiceCall() {
         Methodo_app.WebService1.HelloWorld("someone",onSuccess);
         return false;
}

function onSuccess(result) {
         alert(result);
}
```

After this, i've cancelled this i've modified the function HelloWorld with a simply

```
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
           Return "Hello World"
End Function
```

But in the function WebServiceCall() i still see the old HelloWorld with "ToSomeone" parameters, but this function doesn't exist in my project O.o

I can't explain this O.o

SOme Help?

Comment: Your question is missing any information about the service reference, so I'm guessing you may have missed this:  Generally, a we service call calls a method on a remote web server.  Changing your code locally won't change the results of the web service call...  You'd need to publish your changes to the web server that the code is actually being executed at to see the changes.

Comment: emh... well the webservice was a file in my projects, i've tryed to delete the file, but i still have this problem :S